# How do I create a Pandas DataFrame from my own data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have two financial assets that I'd like to plot price histories for in a Google Colab. The data for one of them is coming from Yahoo Finance. For the other I have it in a Google Sheet.

This works as expected for the one coming from Yahoo:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pd
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='yahoo', start='08-01-2004')
plt.plot(df['Close'])
```

[image]

This does NOT work as expected for the one coming from a Google Sheet:

```
# Asset - Fund - Vanguard Target Retirement 2040
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
k = 'removed-but-valid-docs-key'
w = gc.open_by_key(k).sheet1
r = w.get_all_values()

# Throw away everything before and including the column headings
r = r[r.index(['Date', 'NAV (GBP)']) + 1:]

asset_vanguard = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(r, columns = ['Date', 'Close']).set_index('Date')

# Remove the pound sign in the prices
asset_vanguard['Close'] = asset_vanguard['Close'].str.replace("£", "")

plt.plot(asset_vanguard['Close'])
```

[image]

Inspecting the type of data for the first one:

```
type(df['Close'])

pandas.core.series.Series
```

And the same for the second one:

```
type(asset_vanguard['Close'])

pandas.core.series.Series
```

But debug printing the second data frame shows some output that has a dtype of "object":

```
asset_vanguard['Close']

Date
26 Mar 2021    168.4180
25 Mar 2021    167.2027
24 Mar 2021    167.1827
23 Mar 2021    167.4656
22 Mar 2021    167.8692
                 ...   
23 Dec 2015    101.1195
22 Dec 2015    100.1915
21 Dec 2015     99.4735
18 Dec 2015     99.2277
17 Dec 2015    100.0000
Name: Close, Length: 1334, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the index [**`to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and the `Close` column [**`astype(float)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) before plotting:

```py
asset_vanguard.index = pd.to_datetime(asset_vanguard.index)
asset_vanguard['Close'] = asset_vanguard['Close'].astype(float)

plt.plot(asset_vanguard['Close'])
```